# Deduce that $f$ is integrable.

Tags: calculus

Let $f(x) = 2$ for $0 < x < 1$, and let $f(x) = 1$ at $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. Let $P_n = \{0, 1/n, 1 - 1/n, 1\}$ be a partition on $[0, 1]$. Evaluate $U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n)$. Deduce that $f$ is integrable on $[0, 1]$ and find $\int_0^1 f$.

Comment: Care to tell us what you have tried?

Comment: I've tried finding $m_i$ and $M_i$ for the function, but I'm having trouble determining the supremum and infimum of the set (unless I'm overthinking this)...

Comment: From there, couldn't I show that $U(f, P_n) - L(f, P_n) < \varepsilon$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have: $U(f,P_n) = 2\left(\dfrac{1}{n}-0\right) + 2\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n} - \dfrac{1}{n}\right) + 2\left(1- \left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right)= 2$, and $L(f,P_n) = 1\left(\dfrac{1}{n}- 0\right)+2\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)+1\left(1-\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right)= 2- \dfrac{2}{n}$. Thus:
$U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n) = 2-\left(2-\dfrac{2}{n}\right)= \dfrac{2}{n}$. Thus for any $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N \geq 1+\dfrac{2}{\epsilon}$ and if $n > N \Rightarrow U(f,P_n) - L(f,P_n) < \epsilon$, hence $f$ is integrable, and $\displaystyle \int_{0}^1 f(x)dx = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} L(f,P_n) = 2$.